# Msvcr100d.dll missing when build project in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I use VS2013 on Win 8.1 (I don't install VS2010). 
I have solution file(version 2010). When run in on VS2013, I have just converted to version 2013.
I click run my project, success but show error "MSVCR100D.dll missing"
Please, help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the redistributable package that is installed with VS2010. You can download the package here, which should include that dll: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

Comment: Yeah. I installed it but couldn't success :(